# Styled component styling not working on different react-router routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, styled-components

I am creating a simple recipe retrieval app using Create-react-app with styled-components and react-router. On the home component path='/' styled components works fine, but when navigating to different links, for example, a single recipe, none of the styling works. I created a dummy test component to see if that route works with the styling and found that it only work on the first refresh of the page. If you link back to home and back to the dummy component, styling is gone.

I have tried different types of routers, for example 'connected-react-router' and 'BrowerRouter', i have tried the render props method for the components on the different Routes, I have tried screaming at the computer and contemplating quitting webdev all together, but seem to be out of options now. not much on google as pointed in any helpful direction.

these are the routes

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/recipe" component={Recipe} />
  <Route path="/other" component={Other} />
</Switch>
```

an example of styled-component styling that is not working

```
export const OtherCont = styled.div`
  background-color: blue;
`;
```

and the simple dummy component who's style is not working when navigated to.

```
import { OtherCont } from './styled';

const Other = () => {
  return <OtherCont>bla</OtherCont>;
};
```

I have written many styled components before, I dont think its a problem with syntax, maybe a problem with the version of styled components or react router im using?

```
"react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"styled-components": "^4.3.2"
```

Comment: There is a thing for sure: your router isn't responsible of that. Because of _import caching_ you instance exported will be the same for every component, and that's it. Post a complete snippet reproducing the issue on stackblitz or similar

Comment: Hey! Did you find the issues?

Comment: Was there a solution to this? I think I am having the same issue

Comment: Is there any update on this? I am having the same issue with the following scenario:
- locally build package
- link the package to project A

Comment: It was quite a while ago, but I think it ended up being something completely unrelated that was going wrong and causing the issue